# where does this variable come from

Tags: javascript

This is from [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work). The first answer makes zero sense to me and I can't comment on it. It is extremely frustrating

```
function foo(x) {
  var tmp = 3;
  return function(y) {
    alert(x + y + (++tmp));
  }
}
var bar = foo(2); // bar is now a reference to the closure returned by foo
bar(10);
```

What does this mean? Where does the `y` variable come from?

Comment: Umm.. are you serious?

Comment: Why are there downvotes for this question?  It's a completely legitimate question about a concept that a lot of people struggle with.

Comment: y is just a parameter for the function you're creating in the return value of foo. It's declared in return function (y) just like x is declared in function foo(x)

Comment: @steaks I think it has something to do with the language in the original posting.

Comment: @DanTeesdale Oh, I see why now after looking at the revision history...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For where the variables come from:

```
function foo(x) {       // x introduced
  var tmp = 3;          // tmp introduced
  return function (y) { // y introduced
    // Can access all variables in scope, as introduced above.
    // However, ONLY x and tmp are closed-over as y is just a parameter
    // to the inner function.
    alert(x + y + (++tmp));
  }
}

var bar = foo(2);  // 2 is value for x
bar(10);           // 10 is value for y
```

Now, looking a bit deeper:

`foo(2)` returns a *new* function-object (the inner function) which is bound to two variables (x which currently has the value 2, and tmp which currently has the value 3).

Then `bar(10)` *runs* that function-object passing in 10 (which is then the value of y).

Calling `bar(10)` repeatedly will result in *different* values as a closed-over variable `tmp` is re-assinged (`++tmp`) during the function invocation.

Comment: okay thanks! for some reason I didn't get the concept of a function returning another function

Comment: @JessicaShu Not all languages have it - but once you see it, you can never forget it :D A big concept in JavaScript is that functions are just objects and can be passed around like any other value. A prominent result of this is closures as a function can be invoked from a scope other in which it was defined - I'm not sure that closures can exist without this property, although I'm not a theoretical language expert.

Comment: @Jessica: Such functions are called *higher-order functions*. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher_order_function

Answer (score 3):

You need to distinguish between **variables** (a name for a piece of memory containing information) and **parameters** (placeholder for a variable to be passed into a function).
(Actually it's called a **formal parameter** in the prototype of the function and an **actual parameter** when used in the function body.)
So `y` is not an existing variable but a placeholder for a variable (or value) to be passed in.

You then need to understand that `var func = function(){}` turns `func` into a reference to an anonymous function (a function without a name).
A simplified example would be:

```
var func = function (y) {
   alert(y);
}
func("hello");
```

You can work up from that. Everything else is just the same principle applied in a way of nesting.

Comment: Why does there *need* to be a distinction? (They are both variables in JavaScript and behave darn-near identically - as can be seen the `x` "parameter" is used as a "variable" in the closure.)

Comment: There's not much difference. Both are names for places in memory, one is declared as part of a parameter list the other with a variable declaration statement in function body. The parameter variable gets assigned implicitly when an argument was passed for it, but from then on they work exactly the same. *`y` is a placeholder for a variable to be passed in* is definitely wrong.

Comment: The term **variable** is really ambiguous here. You are likely thinking about a value somewhere in memory. But when this value gets passed as an argument it's original name is aliased (to the name of the parameter). It's actually the very same variable (ignoring the underlying pass-by-value mechanism). So there is never a variable `y` is just the name for what gets passed in.

Comment: That is presuming implementation details (which are, unlike the JLS, not discussed in the ECMAScript specification). Using such terminology is not required to explain the behavior in JavaScript. A variable is simply a *name* (perhaps one of many) for a particular value. (The other behavior is explained by noting that variables are both mutable, variables belong to execution scopes, and that objects are mutable.)

Comment: FWIW, variable definitions and parameters both create bindings in the execution environment, so eventually there is no difference between them. For more detailed info, have a look at the spec: http://es5.github.io/#x10.5.

Answer (score 0):

`foo` is returning a function, which takes one argument called `y`.

So, when you call foo you get a function back, which you can execute whenever you like with an argument, which becomes the value of `y`.

Notice that the returned function is anonymous, but as `foo` returns it, you can effectively bind the function to a variable. Here, `foo` is being called, and the return value is being assigned to `bar`.

Now, you may ask "well, if the function return has the argument `y`, and I call `bar(10)`, now `y` is given the value `10`, but now what's `x`?

Well, `x` already has a value, which it got when `foo` was first called. Here's a "workflow" representation.

1. A function called `foo` is defined, which takes one argument `x`. It returns an anonymous function which takes one argument called `y`.
2. The function `foo` is called with a value of `x` equal to 2, and it's return value is bound to `bar`. `bar` is now a reference to the anonymous function, inside which all values of x are equal to the value of `x` `foo` was called with, i.e. 2.
3. When the anonymous function bound to `bar` is called with `bar(10)`, the argument `y` is given the value `10`. `bar` executes the following

   alert(2 + 10 + (++tmp));

So you might ask now, "what's tmp then"? Well, that should be reasonably straightforward to deduce if you followed the above. When the anonymous function was returned from `foo`, any references of variables local to were bound to the values `foo` had a